# Win/Forms: How do I include Dependencies (DLLS) in Advanced Installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dll, dependencies, advanced-installer

I am total beginner in wondows forms & c#, so please bear with me.

I am integrating Chromium Embeded (CEF) into the project for embedded browsers.

This is running all fine and dandy in Visual Studio, However when I build the App using my Advanced Installer trial it is not including (I believe) the .dll files which I imported into Visual Studio and it is also missing the .dll files which I places in my Bin folder.

I have been working along tutorials like this to include CEF : http://joelverhagen.com/blog/2013/12/headless-chromium-in-c-with-cefglue/

This result when I run the .msi is the "The application has stopped working" message and a error message

> Problem signature:
>     Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
>     Application Name: HotSpot Pro.exe
>     Application Version:  1.0.0.0
>     Application Timestamp:    5385b6bc
>     Fault Module Name:    libcef.DLL
>     Fault Module Version: 3.1650.1522.0
>     Fault Module Timestamp:   52901557
>     Exception Code:   4000001f
>     Exception Offset: 00117430
>     OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
>     Locale ID:    2057
>     Additional Information 1: fe58
>     Additional Information 2: fe5878624072c940bf7f09e916e37fe3
>     Additional Information 3: 5e84
>     Additional Information 4: 5e842ab4bb98e8958a26054cfcd97bd4

Does anyone know how to include these files in the .msi installer? Or is something else going terribly wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Hi!. Did you set the "Copy Local" property to True for all DLLs you need on the References' branch of your project? Check your build settings too. []'s

Comment: yeah this is set, same error occurs.

Comment: What do you mean by []'s? What am i checking in build settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using the full GUI version Advanced Installer, not the VS extension?
If you are using the full version of your application, just go to Files and Folders, there you  can either drag and drop the files missing, if you know which does are, or right click on the main application executable/DLLs and from the context menu select "Add Dependencies".

This option should help you adding the project the dependencies required.

Comment: yeah the installer is placing the files in the ProgramFiles folder, however on launch i still get the error message....

Comment: Woopse I missed a file in the installer! Really crappy error message did't help, thanks!